# Proper way of implementing multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I would like to make an array of arrays with keys associated, and I don't really know what is the proper way to do it.
For example if I have

```
    $array1 = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
$array2 = array(
    "foo2" => "bar2",
    "bar2" => "foo2",
);
```

Would it be correct to write:

```
$key_array=array("first"=>$array1,
                  "second"=>$array2);
```

And, if not, how should I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think it would have been faster if you had tried and discovered that indeed it would work

Comment: Yes it's totally correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. Thank you both

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct, in fact you could also do:

```
$key_array = array(
               'first' => array('first' => $array1, 'second' => $array2),
               'second' => array('first' => $arra1, 'second' => $array2)
             );
```

and nest it as deep as you want.